# Airconsole Simulator screen not connecting

Tags: airconsole

Experimenting with the [Airconsole](https://www.airconsole.com/) platform and I've created a simple placeholder screen and controller. The `/screen.html` and `/controller.html` files display fine on my browser at `myIPAddress:3000`.

I can also access them on a mobile device connected to the same network at `myIPAddress:3000`.

When I attempt to use the Airconsole Simulator, with `myIP` (ie `http://www.airconsole.com/simulator/#http://myIP:3000/`), the controllers connect and display my placeholder content. The screen continues to show the `Loading...` screen indefinitely.

Same thing happens using the local test - `http://www.airconsole.com/?http=1#http://myIP:3000/`. I open that URL in my browser, then open the Airconsole mobile app and enter the game code. It detects a connection and my phone displays the placeholder. The screen continues showing the `Loading...` icon.

Both pages have the `airconsole.js` file included.

Has anyone encountered this? If so, how were you able to resolve it? Any tips for debugging it for more info is also welcomed.

Comment: Do you create an AirConsole instance in the screen? Like new AirConsole()?

Comment: That would be the issue. Working as expected now. If you want to post that as an answer others might find it helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to instantiate the AirConsole object like:

```
var airconsole = new AirConsole();
```

This internally calls the parent frame, which then removes the loading frame etc. and the screen.html is displayed. Or in other words, AirConsole knows you want to start showing your game.

Note: also until then, **no** communication with the loading device works either.